# Differences between Spark Jupyter notebook and PySpark Jupyter Notebook in AWS EMR Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am new to AWS EMR. Started to use Jupyter Notebook on a cluster. There are two options when opening a Jupyter Notebook: PySpark or Spark.

I notice that, with PySpark Notebook, some Python libraries such as `pandas`, `numpy`,... can be imported. But with Spark Notebook, those libraries are not available.
So what are the differences between the two Jupyter Notebooks in AWS EMR?

For the Jupyter PySpark, where and how do I install other Python packages that are available to import?

Comment: spark is written in scala, so spark is scala version and pyspark is python.

Comment: Jupyter has the option for opening a terminal where you can `pip install`, but the more practical solution for EMR is to bake the dependencies in your own AMI, that way the whole cluster has the same dependencies